# Full wave rectifier with capacitor filter

Tags: capacitor, diodes, filter, rectifier

In the figure-1 what is the point of connecting wires to earth? Can we connect all these earthed wires together as in figure-2? (that will make more sense)[image: Figure-1][image: Figure-2]

Comment: Safety.  If a ground fault occurs, circuit protection will activate.

Comment: Although that symbol looks like an earth symbol it is very rare in electronics that it really means "earth" (or mains earth). It simply means that all similar symbols are connected together as you have shown with the red line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All like ground symbols are connected together. That is the point of the symbol -- to indicate all of the nodes that are connected to ground. It simply cleans up the schematic because it prevents wires from being shown across the entire schematic.

All identical ground symbols indicate the same node.

Comment: It is important to note that the schematic shows a mains safety 'Earth' symbol.  It does not mean that the symbols are simply connected together ....it means that plus they are connected to the mains earth.

Comment: @JackCreasey Of course, the node is defined as earth ground, so obviously it should be connected as such. I thought that was implied. My point is that electrically, all of the ground symbols are connected to the same earth ground.

Comment: There is no indication the op understands the difference between safety grounded or not.

Comment: Fair enough, that is definitely important for him to understand when playing with this sort of circuit.

Comment: Tell me i understood correctly or not, here earth acts as single wire, to which all nodes are connected? I also liked the comment of Steve G.

Comment: @user7610737 Every ground symbol you see in the schematic is connected together. However, you must also connect this node to mains earth ground for safety reasons.